# Greenshot Not Working and Reinstallation failed

Tags: windows-11, greenshot

Greenshot unable to be activated using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrnScrn</kbd>. Tried to uninstall and install againt, but with the following error:

```
Software version: 1.2.10.6-RELEASE-c2414cf0149a1475ea00520effc01b40087c225c (64 bit)
.NET runtime version: 4.0.30319.42000+
Time: 2022-05-19 13:37:12 +08:00
OS: unknown   (x64)  10.0 build 22000 revision 0
GDI object count: 50
User object count: 62

Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'LinqBridge, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2b14eb747628076' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Stack:
   at GreenshotPlugin.Core.ClipboardHelper.ContainsImage(IDataObject dataObject)
   at Greenshot.ImageEditorForm.UpdateClipboardSurfaceDependencies()
   at Greenshot.ImageEditorForm.ImageEditorFormActivated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnActivated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Active(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmActivate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Configuration dump:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help with few information, but some comments on what you wrote:

If Greenshot is running (?), but does not react to hotkeys, this might be caused by other software occupying the same hotkey, try changing the hotkey, also see https://getgreenshot.org/faq/my-prntscreen-key-no-longer-works-with-greenshot/

The error message you posted looks as if your 2nd installation is corrupt. Are you sure you downloaded Greenshot from the original website (getgreenshot.org)? I suggest you try to uninstall it completely and then install again using the official installer.